# Insert values from another table and update original table with returning values

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-returning

I'm new to PostgreSQL (and even Stackoverflow).
Say, I have two tables `Order` and `Delivery`:

`Order`

```
id     product      address           delivery_id
--------------------------------------------------
1      apple        mac street        (null)
3      coffee       java island       (null)
4      window       micro street      (null)
```

`Delivery`

```
id     address
----------------
```

`Delivery.id` and `Order.id` are auto-incrementing serial columns.
The table `Delivery` is currently empty.

I would like to move `Order.address` to `Delivery.address` and its `Delivery.id` to `Order.delivery_id` to arrive at this state:

`Order`

```
id     product      address           delivery_id
--------------------------------------------------
1      apple        mac street        1
5      coffee       java island       2
7      window       micro street      3
```

`Delivery`

```
id     address
---------------------
1      mac street
2      java island
3      micro street
```

I'll then remove `Order.address`.

I found a similar question for Oracle but failed to convert it to PostgreSQL:

- [How to insert values from one table into another and then update the original table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758015/how-to-insert-values-from-one-table-into-another-and-then-update-the-original-ta)

I still think it should be possible to use a plain SQL statement with the `RETURNING` clause and a following `INSERT` in Postgres.

I tried this (as well as some variants):

```sql
WITH ids AS (
    INSERT INTO Delivery (address)
    SELECT address
    FROM Order
    RETURNING Delivery.id AS d_id, Order.id AS o_id
)
UPDATE Order
SET Delivery_id = d_id
FROM ids
WHERE Order.id = ids.o_id;
```

This latest attempt failed with:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Delivery" LINE 1: ...address Order RETURNING Delivery.id...

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `ORDER` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Don't use it as identifier. Assuming `orders` as table nae instead.

```sql
WITH ids AS (
   INSERT INTO delivery (address)
   SELECT DISTINCT address
   FROM   orders
   ORDER  BY address -- optional
   RETURNING *
   )
UPDATE orders o
SET    delivery_id = i.id
FROM   ids i
WHERE  o.address = i.address;
```

You have to account for possible duplicates in `order.address`. `SELECT DISTINCT` produces unique addresses.

In the outer `UPDATE` we can now join back on `address` because `delivery.address` is unique. You should probably keep it that way beyond this statement and add a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) on the column.

Effectively results in a one-to-many relationship between `delivery` and `orders`. One row in `delivery` can have many corresponding rows in `orders`. Consider to enforce that by adding a [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) accordingly.

This statement enjoys the benefit of starting out on an empty `delivery` table. If `delivery` wasn't empty, we'd have to work with an UPSERT instead of the `INSERT`. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Related:

- [Insert data in 3 tables at a time using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561254/insert-data-in-3-tables-at-a-time-using-postgres/20561627#20561627)

About the cause for the error message you got:

- [RETURNING causes error: missing FROM-clause entry for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153884/returning-causes-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table/67154373#67154373)

Use legal, lower-case identifiers exclusively, if you can. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: This logic fails if the addresses aren't guaranteed to be unique, I think?

Comment: @DonR: This statement is designed to deal with duplicate addresses. How would you expect it to fail?

Comment: I was, perhaps mistakenly, assuming the OP wanted a 1-1 relationship; I ought to have asked for clarification before proceeding on that assumption.

Comment: In fact, I intended 1-1 relationship, you assumed correcly @DonR. Because there is much more columns in real ```Delivery``` table. It's my fault. I had to more clarify my question.

Comment: However anyway, @ErwinBrandstetter 's answer is also super helpful. If someone see this post and is looking for a measure for 1-many relationship this will be the best answer for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return columns from the **FROM** relation in the **RETURNING** clause of the CTE query. You'll have to either manage this in a cursor, or add an **order_id** column to the **Delivery** table, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Delivery ADD COLUMNN order_id INTEGER:

INSERT INTO Delivery (address, order_id)
    SELECT address, id
    FROM Order
;

WITH q_ids AS
(
    SELECT id, order_id
    FROM Delivery
)
UPDATE Order
SET delivery_id = q_ids.id
FROM q_ids
WHERE Order.id = q_ids.order_id;
```